# prevalence ratio question

Tags: epidemiology, prevalence

I understand that prevalence ratio is

```
                            Number of people in sample with characteristic
        Prevalence ratio =  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                 Total # of people in sample
```

https://www.nimh.nih.gov/health/statistics/what-is-prevalence

My question is does the denominator in this formula include the numerator ? Are the number of people with disease included in the Total # of people in the sample ?

Comment: Aside: [Why do some researchers use the oxymoron "prevalence *rate*"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493757/why-do-some-researchers-use-the-oxymoron-prevalence-rate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes. The denominator includes the numerator.**

A prevalence can be understood as measuring the proportion of people in a population sharing some characteristic. So:

$$\text{Prevalence of }X\text{ in pop.} = \frac{\text{No. people with }X\text{ in pop.} }{\text{No. people with }X \text{ in pop.} + \text{No. people without }X \text{ in pop.}}$$